# How can the JPA recognize two classes with the same name but in different packages?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I use JPA and Hibernate for my project. I have two classes with **same names** but in **different packages**. They are:

```
@Entity(name = "X_USER")
@Table(name = "X_USER")
public class User {
```

and:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Y_USER")
public class User {
```

I was creating a search query with: `.getSimpleName()` but it didn't work because their simple name are the same. I changed it to `.getName()`.

However, it still confuses to which `User` to return.

**EDIT:**

I have that:

```
SELECT_BY_PROPERTY_QUERY = "SELECT p FROM :CLASS: p WHERE p.:PROPNAME:=?";
```

and I that:

```
SELECT_BY_PROPERTY_QUERY.replaceFirst(":CLASS:", clazz.getName()).replaceFirst(":PROPNAME:", propertyName);
```

and when I debug it it makes something like:

```
Select p from User p Where p.name=?
```

It is still `User` and it doesn't include package information and returns me wrong `User` class.

Comment: `getName()` should be returning the FQN. What error are you getting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to create a JPQL query you need to pass the **Entity name** to it. As you posted, you have 2 entities which are represented by the **same** Java class, but **different** Entity name (`X_USER` explicitly set by you and `User` set implicitly).

If you want to get dynamically the name of the entity you should rather use the [`Metamodel`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/metamodel/Metamodel.html), so something like this should do the work (not checked):

```
EntityManager em = ...
Metamodel model = em.getEntityManagerFactory().getMetamodel();
String entityName = model.entity(com.your.pckg.User.class).getName();
```

HTH.